# Nodes_modules packages duplicated

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Im using npm to install several packages for my application.

So I got one node_modules that contains all the packages. However several packages contains itself some node_modules and these node_modules contains other packages...

My problem is that the packages may be duplicated in the several node_modules, so I m searching a solution to remove this duplications.

This what I have tried :

- npm dedupe : it doesnt resolve my problem and the duplication still present
- flatten-packages : this resolved the duplciations but my app stopped to work because it says that the packages are not finding the dependencies it needs....

I m using npm 6.1.0

here are an example of my dependencies and devDependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.0",
    "cpx": "^1.5.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "0.0.3",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.1",
    "object-mapper": "^5.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-intl": "^2.4.0",
    "react-number-format": "^3.3.1",
    "react-promise": "^2.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
    "jest": "^22.4.4"
  }
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you explain why you'd like to remove the duplicates?

Comment: because we have a security check that should be run within 5 minutes and since the node_modules is big th security check failed ...

Comment: Are you sure they are duplicated?  Are they the same version?  Can you show a minimal `package.json` and `package-lock.json` to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Also, can you explain the security check?  That just raises more questions to me and makes this almost feel like an XY problem.

Comment: yes I m sure that are duplicated , I ve run npm ls and count the number of duplications : here are some : 
16 | | | | | +-- postcss@5.2.18
      16 | | | | | |   `-- has-flag@1.0.0
      16 | | | | | | `-- supports-color@3.2.3
      16 | | | | | | +-- chalk@1.1.3 deduped
      16 | | | | | | +-- js-base64@2.4.6 deduped
      16 | | | | | | +-- source-map@0.5.7
      15 | | | | | +-- babel-runtime@6.26.0 deduped
      11 | | | | | `-- babel-runtime@6.26.0 deduped
      10 | | | | | `-- postcss-value-parser@3.3.0 deduped
      10 | | | | | | +-- babel-runtime@6.26.0 deduped

Comment: npm version is also relevant

Comment: I m using npm 6.1.0 - last version

Comment: we are using https://fr.sonatype.com/nexus-iq-server to check the security -- and check if some packages are vulnarable ....

Comment: could you also add 'dependencies' and 'devDependencies' sections of package.json ?

Comment: I updated my post to include dep and devDep as suggested

Answer (score 0):

There can be different versions of same package.
if dependency 'A' needs dependency 'B' with version specified as '^1.0.0'
and another dependency 'C' needs dependency 'B' but with version specified as '^2.0.0'

Package managers can put a less used version inside node_modules of another package.
It is by design.

Comment: Some of my packages needs the same version of dependencies .. and I want these to be shared in the root node_modules .. actually they are duplicated ....